# Enforcing Google Colab to use another python version

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Well, I'm trying to use Python 3.7.16 on Google Colab, I'm using the following command to install it:

```
!sudo apt-get install python3.7
!sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
!sudo apt-get update
!sudo apt-get install python3-pip
!sudo apt-get install python3.7-distutils
!sudo apt-get install python3-apt
!sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev
```

Then, I update the alternatives...

```
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 1
!sudo update-alternatives --set python3 $(update-alternatives --list python3 | grep python3.7)
!sudo update-alternatives --set python $(update-alternatives --list python3 | grep python3.7)
```

I tried both...

Then, I check the version:

```
!python -V
!python3 -V
!which python
!which python3
!/usr/local/bin/python -V
!/usr/bin/python -V
import sys
print(sys.version)
print(sys.executable)
```

This is prompted:

```
Python 3.7.16
Python 3.7.16
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python3
Python 3.7.16
Python 3.7.16
3.9.16 (main, Dec  7 2022, 01:11:51) 
[GCC 9.4.0]
/usr/bin/python3
```

Why the python part:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
print(sys.executable)
```

Prints 3.9 version.

I need that the same python environment is used when I execute scripts, not only executing the bash script, because I installed pip packages and they are out of context.

Also, I cannot wget a python script from outside, because the context is also lost on the next cells...

Conda or venv aren't my friends here because I already tried them and they have the same result. They are executed on a environment different from the cell...